Access denied when trying to access path - Flutter Windows Desktop program
I'm trying to access the temp path but I receive the access denied message, how do I make the program show the window to grant authorization?
the error message I get is this:
[ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(41)] Unhandled Exception: PathAccessException: Cannot open file, path = 'C:\Users\xabla\AppData\Local\Temp' (OS Error: Acesso negado.

Here is the example code that causes access denied:
static Future<void> getFiles() async {
  PermissionStatus status = await Permission.storage.request();
  Directory path = await getTemporaryDirectory();

  File file = File(path.path);

  if (!status.isDenied) {
    try {
      List<String> foo = await file.readAsLines();
      log(foo.toString());
    } catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
}


Show us your code - we can't help you otherwise.

"how do I make the program show the window to grant authorization?" - UAC Elevation should never be required: a user's process should always be able to open %temp% - I'm guessing either the filesystem NTFS ACLs are broken - or you're trying to access the Temp directory of a different user account entirely?

I'm trying to list the files and folders in the temp folder through the program I'm writing in flutter/dart.
